# Array initialization without the keyword "new"

Tags: c#, arrays, heap-memory, stack-memory

In C# it is possible to initialize an array without the keyword "new" like in the following example:

```
int[] x = { 10, 20, 30 };
```

Does this mean that the array will be initialized on the stack since the keyword "new" is necessary to initialize something on the heap?

Comment: Syntactic sugar is different from a new language construct. It's the same as any other array.

Comment: you might be looking for the stackalloc keyword http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx

Comment: If you're using managed code, then no. Every object requires the `new` keyword in order to, well, allocate the memory. Unmanaged code is a whole different beast, and there probably exists a way to do that, as above. I remember reading somewhere that there was a way to "defer" the constructor, but it still needs to be called at some point before the object is in a usable state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: No.

The code you show  is shorthand for `int[] x = new [] { 10, 20, 30 }`
which is shorthand for `int[] x = new int[] { 10, 20, 30}`
which is shorthand for `int[] x = new int[3]; x[0] = 10; x[1] = 20; x[2] = 30;`

(see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664573(v=vs.71).aspx))

There is no difference in implementation.

The only way of allocating an array on the stack is using unsafe code with the `stackalloc` keyword, as pointed out in the comments. 
Example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/cx9s2sy4.aspx):

```
int* block = stackalloc int[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add something more here.

> What you will have in stack is the heapAddress of your int Array. Let
>   say when you are passing that array into some function then what you
>   are passing is the heapAddress value from Stack.

Answer (score -1):

The intermediate code that gets generated is same for new and without new initializes.

Sample code:

```
 public class Class1
{
    int[] a = new int[4];
}

public class Class2
{
    int[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

Compiled:

(Since i do not have the necessary points to upload images, you can view it in ildasm)